# Wildcard ssl certificate (*.blog.mydomain.com) not working on blog.mydomain.com

Tags: ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain

I have a web app in Azure. I have requested wildcard ssl certificate for ***.blog.mydomain.com**. I was going to use it on all blog subdomains as well as on **blog.mydomain.com**. However when I try to bind it on **blog.mydomain.com** it doesn't accept it. What could be the reason?

Comment: This isn't a question about programming, so it's off-topic for StackOverflow.  It would be on-topic in the [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) site. Anyway, you're getting the expected behaviour.  The wildcard matches a name followed by `.blog.mydomain.com`, and the `blog.mydomain.com` string does not follow that pattern.  If you want the cert to apply to `blog.mydomain.com` in addition to the wildcard then the cert's Subject Alternative Name field must include `blog.mydomain.com`.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify both subject names `blog.mydomain.com` and `*. blog.mydomain.com` in the certificate's SAN.

Comment: Just updating the correct answer. I have regenerated ssl certificate with CSR which contained both *. blog.mydomain.com and blog.mydomain.com and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Which correct answer?

`*.mydomain.com` would make a whole lot more sense, because it covers all of these.

It even circumvents the idea of using wildcards, to still add multiple host-names.

If the `blog` is another server with another IP, this might be the only exception.

Comment: Its a quirk/feature of SSL name resolution in the  SAN. `*.mydomain.com` is not the same as `mydomain.com`. The wild card domain does *not* resolve to the root domain name.  You will need both, as my answer correctly describes.  I agree with you that is not immediately obvious why that is necessary. But it is. See https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/wildcard-san-names.htm for an explanation.